# Table not formatting correctly

Tags: tables, formatting

I'm getting a bit of a strange output when I code in the following:

**Code:**

```
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}m{15mm}|>{\centering}m{15mm}|>{\centering}m{15mm}|>{\centering}m{15mm}|>{\centering}m{15mm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Element}}    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Local Nodes}}   &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Global Nodes}}\\
\hline
a & a & a & a & a \\
\end{tabular}\\
```

The final column of the second row (i.e. the one with the 'a's) is misformatted. 
Additionally, when I try to add more lines to the table, it likes to add the first entry into the fifth column.

I have a feeling I'm just missing a typo in my code.

For reference, here's the preamble:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=ieee,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\title{\bfseries\sffamily\Huge XX}
\author{\sffamily XX}
\date{\sffamily XX}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\sffamily\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\Huge \bfseries \sffamily Contents}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} %This removes the standard indentation from the 
beginning of paragraphs
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\Huge\bfseries\sffamily} % format
{\Huge{\thechapter}\hspace{2mm}}                % label
{0pt}             % sep
{\Huge}           % before-code 
\titleformat{\section}
{\Large\bfseries\sffamily} % format
{\Large{\thesection}\hspace{2mm}}                % label
{0pt}             % sep
{\Large}           % before-code 
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\sffamily\large\bfseries}
{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries}
{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{} 
\usepackage[font=sf]{caption}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{array}
\raggedright
\usepackage{subfiles}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
```

**Output**
[image: Output]

Comment: Off-topic but relevant nevertheless: The `hyperref` package should be loaded *last* in the preamble of your document. Also: The `palatino` package is considered deprecated; load the package `newpxtext` instead. (I see you're also loading the `fourier` package, presumably for math material. An alternative to `fourier` would be `newpxmath`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

you should add `\arraybackslash` after `\centering` at least in the last column:

```
\begin{tabular}{|*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{15mm}|}}
    \hline
\textbf{Element}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Local Nodes}}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Global Nodes}}  \\
    \hline
a & a & a & a & a                                       \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

**edit:**
as Mico suggested in his comment below, you can for simpler table typing define new column type for example as:

```
newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
```

and then use it as

```
\begin{tabular}{|*{5}{M{15mm}|}}
```

(in case of equal width of columns) or for example

```
\begin{tabular}{|M{15mm}| M{20mm}| M{20mm}| M{10mm}| M{10mm}|}
```

when their width are different.

Comment: @MosheHollander, you can accept answer by clicking on check mark on the top left side of answer :). happy tex-ing!

Comment: +1. Since the same column type -- `>{\centering\arraybackslash}m` -- is used 5 times -- you may want to advise the OP to set up a newcolumn type, called (say) `M`, as follows: `\newcolumntype{M}[1]{{#1}}`. Then, the header of the `tabular` environment may be written more succinctly as `\begin{tabular}{|*{5}{M{15mm}|}}`. :-)